# Laravel4/PHP Model(or anything) extend multiple classes

Tags: php, oop, laravel, laravel-4

I found some useful packages that extend the functionality of Eloquent, For example: Sentry, Revisionable.
Now I understand that you cannot extend multiple classes, and that there are ways as proxies or just using another class as a property somehow.

What would be the best practice to create a model that benefits from multiple packages?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We have some options:

**Dependency Injection:**

```
use ExternalClass;

class Model extends Eloquent {

    private $external;

    public function __construct(ExternalClass $external)
    {
        $this->external = $external;
    }

    public function doWhatever() 
    {
        return $this->external->do();
    }

    public function __call($name, $arguments)
    {
        return call_user_func_array(array($this->external,$name), $arguments);
    }
}
```

You don't have to pass a class to your model, Laravel will try to instantiate and inject that class for you.

**edit**

And you don't have to rewrite all methods, see this magic method `__call`? It will be fired automatically by PHP everytime a method is not found in your class, so you can use it to forward that call to your external class.

**end-edit**

**Traits:** (this is PHP 5.4+)

```
class Model extends Eloquent {

    use MyTraits;

    public function doWhatever() 
    {
        return $this->do();
    }
}

trait MyTraits {

    public function do()
    {
        /// this metho will be available in your class 
    }

}
```

**You can also use the Repository Pattern:**

```
class DataRepository {

    private $user;

    private $external;

    public function __construct(User $user, ExternalClass $external)
    {
        $this->user = $user;

        $this->external = $external;
    }

    public function allUsers() 
    {
        return $this->user->all();
    }

    public function doWhatever() 
    {
        return $this->external->do($this->user);
    }
}
```

There some others, but your project is what will really tell you what's best.

**EDIT**

Note that you have to be aware of the __call magic method, because Laravel also uses it to deliver dynamic methods, like `whereColumnname()` and you risk breaking by using it. But this is also something you can circumvent with a little more code:

```
public function __call($name, $arguments)
{
    // If the method is not one of your package ones, try execute an Eloquent (parent) one

    if ( ! in_array($name, ['methodA', 'methodB', 'methodC']))
    {
        return parent::__call($name, $arguments);
    }
    else
    {
        return call_user_func_array(array($this->external,$name), $arguments);
    }
}
```

Comment: Traits is php 5.4 no? (I'm on 5.3 with current project)

Comment: Dependency injection or/with the repository pattern has, in my experience, led to the most maintainable applications.

Comment: Yeah, so you cannot use Traits, but I think that traits are for other kind of usage anyway. :)

Comment: so basicly, with Dependency Injection I have to rewrite ALL the methods... and props

Comment: Not really, just edited to add a magic method that can save a lot of rewriting.

Comment: but most packages rely on being able to do $this->data, if I'm calling their methods the way you show, will $this be the actual model?

Comment: As long as you instantiate them correctly, passing to them whatever dependencies they need, yes.

Comment: The `__call` fall-through will technically break Laravel's own `__call` fall-trough on Eloquent models, however, as I understand it, so it may not be a good solution.

Comment: Yeah, but this is also something that may be circunvented with a little more code. Edited to show how.

Comment: same with construct, im my team there is a pattern of doing new Model;  so basicly all over the code we will need to change that(to pass the dependencies) and thats not an option.